# What would happen if the opposite complementary variables of two entangled particles were measured at the same time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Many explanations about the uncertainty principle and its related EPR paradox state that it is impossible to measure opposite complementary variables on different entangled particles; for example, measuring the position of one particle and the momentum of the other at the exact time.

I fail to understand what it means for this to be "impossible" in this case. What *would* happen if such an attempt was made?

I can only think of 4 ways of interpreting this impossibility:

1. For every known pair of complementary variables, we only know how to measure one of the two variables for any given particle; for example, we only know how to measure position, not momentum (or vice versa). This is obviously incorrect.
2. It is impossible to measure any of the complementary variables of a particle at the exact time we measure any other complementary variable of another particle. For example, given any two particles, we cannot measure both of their positions at the same time. I'm guessing this is also incorrect.
3. Same as #2, but exclusive for entangled particles, implying that there is something in the process of the creation of such a pair that prevents them from being measured at the same exact time.
4. In the case of an entangled pair being measured at the same time for opposite complementary variables, these measurements would "somehow" no longer correlate between the two, thus rendering the particles entangled no more.

Furthermore, if #4 is the case, was it verified? Was there an experiment showing the measured particles indeed were no longer entangled, perhaps by proof of contradiction; i.e, observing a later measurement that could only occur if these values were different than the values assumed based on the original measurements and the correlation between the particles?

I would love it if the answer would be simple as possible, as I do not have a strong background in neither physics nor mathematics.

Comment: What would happen is that you'd observe some eigenstate of the combined observation, with probabilities given by the Born rule, just as with any other measurement in quantum mechanics.

Comment: In particular, the impossibility assertion that you attribute to "many explanations" is simply false.

Comment: @WillO So that means _it is_ possible to measure / know (not predict) the "incompatible observables" of a particle at a given time -- say its position and its momentum?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible.  What could conceivably prevent it?  Alice gets out her measuring apparatus and uses it in the usual way; Bob, across town, does likewise.  Alice 's choice about what to measure obviously can't constrain Bob.

Comment: @WillO Doesn't that contradicts the uncertainty principle?

Comment: No.  Of course not.

Comment: @WillO How so? Doesn't the principle states that the position and momentum of a particle at a given time cannot be known with precision?

Comment: Not exactly.  It says that a particle can't simultaneously *have* a well defined position and a well defined momentum.  But these are two particles, not one.

Comment: @WillO Sure, these are two particles, but they are entangled, and from what I understand that means that their properties (position and momentum) are correlated. Therefore, I can presumably measure the position of particle A and deduce its momentum as well by measuring particle B's momentum (and calculating the correlated value for A). But then, I understand that this is not possible. Why?

Comment: there are probability distributions for momenta and positions for each particle, and their envelope for each is within the HUP. You can measure with accuracy a probable point in each distribution, *probable* is the crucial word.

Comment: @annav Repeat my last comment, why can't I deduce particle A's momentum as accurately as I've measured its position (that is, deduced via a correlation to the same accurate measurement of B's momentum)?

Comment: You will likely not have access to [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/j.1538-7305.1965.tb01684.x) by Arthurs and Kelly, but in the paper they describe a scheme for simultaneously measuring the position and momentum of a particle.  This can be done provided that there is some uncertainty in both measurements; which is to say, if you prepared the system in the same initial state and repeated the measurements over and over, you would get a spread in the measured values.

Comment: You have to separate accuracy of measurement with uncertainty of value. Take a picture of a goal keeper just before jumping for the ball. You can measure extremely accurately the position of the ball, theposition of the goalkeeper, but cannot predict whether the ball will be caught, as there is a probability that something will go wrong. The HUP aound A and the one around B measurements mean that no matter how accurately you will measure x and p (picture) there is an uncertainty in the correlation between the two states, and you can deduce from A to B only within this uncertainty.

Comment: @annav Thanks, I think I understand your explanation. But then, shouldn't the uncertainty of A's momentum (the one deduced from B's) affect the predictions made from A's momentum (compared to a "simple" more certain measure of it)? If so, was this shown in experiments? This is akin the "furthermore" part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

This has really been fully answered in the comments, but here is more detail:

You want the particles to be in an entangled state that guarantees that momentum measurements on both particles are certain to agree.  So take the entangled state $\xi=A\otimes A+B\otimes B$, where $A$ and $B$ are eigenstates of momentum.  ("Momentum" here can stand for any  observable of your choice.)

Then $X=A+B$ and $Y=A-B$ are eigenstates of the complementary observable (which we can call "position").  Check that (up to multiplication by a constant)

$$\xi=X\otimes X+Y\otimes Y$$

so that position measurements of both particles are also certain to agree.

But

$$\xi=X\otimes A+X\otimes B+Y\otimes A-Y\otimes B$$
so that if you measure the position of the first particle and the momentum of the second, all four outcomes are equally likely.

Moreover, if you measure the position of the first particle and it comes out to be, say, $Y$, then the state collapses to $Y\otimes A-Y\otimes B$, leaving you with maximum uncertainty about the outcome of a momentum measurement on the second.

Comment: Is there a quick way to check that $X,Y$ are eigenstates of a complimentary (in the sense of commuting to a constant) variable?

Comment: @jacob1729 :  I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if you take $A$ and $B$ to be the column vectors $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$, then you can explicitly write down matrices representing momentum and position and can explicitly compute their commutator.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. Is there a smarter way of seeing that (eg X,Y are a 45 degree rotation of A,B).

Comment: "if you measure the position of the first particle ... leaving you with maximum uncertainty about the outcome of a momentum measurement on the second" - but what does that uncertainty mean in practice? As far as I understand the term, "uncertainty" in practice would mean that predictions made using said uncertain measurement will have a weaker correlation with actual results than it would with a more "certain" measurement. For example, predicting the (later) position of the second particle according to its momentum (comparing a certain and uncertain measurements of momentum).

Comment: "maximum uncertainty" here means there's a 50% probability of each outcome.

Comment: @WillO What does that mean? I measured the position of the first particle and the momentum of the second particle -- these are certain. It's only a question now of whether I can deduce their counterparts with certainty, and this I believe could be tested (by assessing whether predictions made from these counterpart measurements hold). Perhaps position/momentum is a problematic pair since momentum depends on time, so measuring them at the exact same time is quite meaningless, but how about spin?

Comment: Try reading the answer.

Comment: @WillO I did, and it doesn't answer my question. Also, telling me to read the answer only comes out as mockery.

Comment: Perhaps when you read the answer you overlooked the line that says you can replace momentum in this argument with any observable of your choice.

Comment: @WillO I merely pointed that out to make sure my further questioning in the comments isn't hindered by _my_ fixation to the position/momentum pair. Giving a general explanation as a means to answer a question might seem obvious to someone familiar with the theory -- who is easily able to frame it in the form of the question -- but may be not so obvious for someone lacking a strong background in physics, requiring a more direct answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you measure the position of one of two entangles particles with infinite precision this doesn't mean that you automatically know the position of the other particle with infinite precision (even though they are entangled). Likewise for momentum measurement. Position and momentum are not quantum entangled. Position and momentum entanglement hold only for the individual particles. If you measure the position of one particle, you know instantaneously that is not at some other position. Likewise for momentum. For spin, on the contrary, you know instantaneously that the spin of the other is opposite if you measure it to be up or down (in the case of fermions).